# ValueError at / Invalid format string

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, models, strftime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8tM6.png)i am making a blog website through Django! While adding the strftime for dates in my project, I am getting Value error! Here are the code in which i get error: ***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:100]

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

Here are the HTML code in which i get error:

```
 {% for blog in blogs.all %}
   <a href=""><h3 >{{ blog.title }}</h3></a>
    {{ blog.pub_date_pretty }}
<br />
    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ blog.image.url }}" height =200 width=200 />
    <br />
    <p>{{ blog.summary }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you post your full error?

Comment: i have posted the models.py full code and should i send the whole html code?

Comment: Say me a specific file

Comment: No, the error traceback you are seeing.

Comment: What do you want to have from this call: `self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')`? %e is an ilegal formatter

Comment: @MegaIng i want just the date to show up but not the time! So i made those

Comment: imgur is not good for traceback. We need to see the many screenfulls. Copy/paste from your console.

Comment: hey as @MegaIng said that %e is an ilegal formatter i deleted the %e and saw that the error was no longer their and i solved my issue! Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this call:

```
self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

`%e` is not a valid directive for `strftime`. If you just want to display the date, use something like this:

```
self.pub_date.strftime('%b %d %Y')
```

You can see a full list of the directives you can use [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)